# Defining methods with double greater than sign (>>) in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

In the book [Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013476904X) from Kent Beck, the double greater sign (`>>`) is used to define methods like this:

```st
Point class>>x: xNumber y: yNumber
    ^self new
        setX: xNumber
        y: yNumber

Point>>setX: xNumber y: yNumber
    x := xNumber.
    y := yNumber.
    ^self
```

However, I cannot get it run in GNU Smalltalk.

Is it valid syntax in some implementation of Smalltalk? Or is it just kind of pseudo code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact this is Pseudo code.

In other languages you would use the `.` to tell people that the method is in this class but in smalltalk you write `>>`

What you would do in a Smalltalk like [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/) or [Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download) for

```
Point class>>x: xNumber y: yNumber
    ^self new
        setX: xNumber
        y: yNumber
```

1. Open the System Browser
2. klick on class, a button that will show you the class side of the class.
3. paste the method in the text area with the source code:

   ```
   x: xNumber y: yNumber
       ^self new
           setX: xNumber
           y: yNumber
   ```
4. Strg-s to save the code

For

```
Point>>setX: xNumber y: yNumber
    x := xNumber.
    y := yNumber.
    ^self
```

You would do the same but not use the class side

Answer (score 4):

Also, notice that indeed, #>> is a message that you can send to a class and it basically access the method dictionary for the symbol (selector argument). See, Behavior class, method >>

```
  >> selector 
"Answer the compiled method associated with the argument, selector (a 
Symbol), a message selector in the receiver's method dictionary. If the 
selector is not in the dictionary, create an error notification."

^self compiledMethodAt: selector
```

So you can do, for example (inspect that)

```
  Point class >> #x:y:
```

Notice however, that here we send #class because #x:y: is a class side method. If you want to access an instance side method, say #normalized then you can do:

```
  Point >> #normalized
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for GNU Smalltalk will look something like this:

```
Point class extend [
    x: xNumber y: yNumber [
        ^self new
            setX: xNumber
            y: yNumber ]
]

Point extend [
    setX: xNumber y: yNumber [
        x := xNumber.
        y := yNumber.
        ^self ]
]
```

For more information on GNU Smalltalk syntax see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/Syntax.html).